# Objective C. Weird syntax

Tags: objective-c

I have found a strange as for me way to declare a method in Objective C.

Method declaration in .h file:

```
-(void)methodName:(NSString *)str, int i;
```

Method implementation in .m file:

```
-(void)methodName:(NSString *)str, int i
{
     NSLog(@"str = %@, int = %d", str, i);
}
```

I can call this method like this:

```
[self methodName:@"stringExample", 99];
```

And it would work fine.

My question is when should I use such syntax. Is there any difference between it and usual declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6), those parameters are *optional*:

> Methods that take a variable number of parameters are also possible,
>   though they’re somewhat rare. Extra parameters are separated by commas
>   after the end of the method name. (Unlike colons, the commas are not
>   considered part of the name.) In the following example, the imaginary
>   makeGroup: method is passed one required parameter (group) and three
>   parameters that are optional:
>
> `[receiver makeGroup:group, memberOne, memberTwo, memberThree];`

So yes, the declaration is different to the usual declaration.  I cannot find any regular use of this type of declaration other than with a varargs method, where the optional parameter is declared as `...`.

Answer (score 1):

The aim in declaring methods like: `-(void)methodName:(NSString *)str yourInt:( int) i{...}` is for making it more readable. After [llvm 4.0](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) declaring strings, arrays, dictionaries .. can be handled like other C languages.. For instance, the both of declarations below are true:

```
//old style
array = [nsarray arraywithobjects:a, b, c, nil];
dict = [nsdictionary dictionarywithobjects:@[o1, o2, o3]
forkeys:@[k1, k2, k3]];
number = [nsnumber numberwithchar:'x'];
number = [nsnumber numberwithint:12345];
//new style
array = @[ a, b, c ];
dict = @{ k1 : o1, k2 : o2, k3 : o3 };
number = @'x';
number = @12345;
```

Resource from a Turkish forum is [here](http://www.eksisozluk.com/show.asp?t=objective-c)